# Syncing 2 multiple choice lists in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, select, return-value, synchronization

I'm trying to figure out how to sync two multiple choice lists in javascript. Here's the code which works:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function SelectEmail(name)
{
    var listboxEmails = document.getElementById('emails');
    for (var i=0;i<listboxEmails.length;i++)
    {
        listboxname = listboxEmails[i].innerHTML
        if (listboxname == name)
        {
            listboxEmails.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }//end for 
}//end function SelectEmail

// -->
</script>
<body>
<select id='names' name ='names' style = "width: 100" multiple="multiple" onClick="SelectEmail(this.value);">
    <option value ="joe">joe</option>
    <option value ="albert">albert</option>
    <option value ="gary">gary</option>
    <option value ="ace">ace</option>
</select>

<select id="emails" name ="emails" style = "width: 100;"  multiple="multiple">
    <option value ="joe@asds.com">joe</option>
    <option value ="albert@asds.com">albert</option>
    <option value ="gary@asds.com">gary</option>
    <option value ="ace@asds.com">ace</option>
</SELECT>
</body>
</html>
```

However I want to make it show multiple choices. So for example if I choose albert and gary on the left list, I want the right list to select albert and gary as well. Please help me with this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `SelectEmail()` can't work because it sets `selectedIndex` of your select, which selects one option and deselects the rest. Also, you are using the text content of the options in `#emails` in order to map them with the values of `#names`. That's not a good practice, because text nodes are supposed to show text and not to enable the identification of elements in your script.
Instead, you can access the `selected` attribute separately for each option you want to select. By adding an additional attribute to your `#emails` element's options, it could look like:

```
<select id="emails" name="emails" style="width: 100;" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="joe@asds.com" data-name="joe">joe</option>
    <option value="albert@asds.com" data-name="albert">albert</option>
    <option value="gary@asds.com" data-name="gary">gary</option>
    <option value="ace@asds.com" data-name="ace">ace</option>
</select>
```

You can now use the `data-name` attribute to map the options, for example in the following way:

```
function selectEmail() {
    // deselect all
    $('#emails option').removeAttr('selected');
    var names = $('#names').val();
    if (names == null) {
        // none selected
        return;
    }
    $.each(names, function (i, name) {
        var selector = 'option[data-name="' + name + '"]';
        $('#emails ' + selector).attr('selected', true);
    });
}
```

Here's a working fiddle (you will notice that I also used the `onchange` event instead of `onclick`:
http://jsfiddle.net/H9hNH/2/